# pass a jquery window.width value to php variable

Tags: php, jquery

This is my javascript. I want to get jquery variable value to php variable in same page without using ajax. I used to print php variable but not show anything. I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
<?php echo 'alert($(window).width();';
$width= '$(window).width();';
echo $width;
?>
```

Comment: Javascript is clientside, php is serverside... you cant do this, and if you could you shouldnt.

Comment: You could do this with a javascript redirect, but it's not very pretty. Get the window width, then do `window.location = "/mypage.php?width=" + $(window).width();`

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side language and jQuery is a client side framework! When you load you php page, it first executes the server side code and then, it would execute your jquery code.

This would result in an empty string to be echoed. If you really want to get the client side window width, use an ajax function to send it your server. But then again I don't know what you are trying to achieve here.

**Please review you application architecture.**

Comment: then how to do with ajax but on same page

Comment: You should have a ajax url to be called where it will handle the payload you send from the front end. you then execute the specific application logic and return the ajax response to the page where you can write your front end logic. before doing that, review your application architecture with a peer. Because, you logic doesn't make any sense.